# Perl regex match based on no. of chars

Tags: regex, perl

I get input string like:

```
A     BC Y
```

Or

```
A     BCY
```

The point being, it is position based,
i.e I have to parse First 1 char as one string, next  7 as another string,  next 1 as another string and the tricky part being last one string as another string (Which is optional in input)
i.e input line length can be 9 chars or 10 chars.
I am supposed to parse this and get 4 Strings.

later I will put these strings in *Database* and do further processing.

I am using regex like

```
s/(.{1})(.{7})(.{1})(.{1})/
```

And copying this values in 4 variables.

But the problem is it works only when the length of line is exactly 10 chars (When we have last char).

When length is 9 chars (last optional char `Y` is missing) Then the regex does not match the line and thus no parsing.

Long story short, How can I modify the `regex` to make the last 1 char optional for parsing.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Question may sound very trivial to experts, But....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `?` for optional (0 or 1) match

```
/(.{1})(.{7})(.{1})(.{1})?/
```

Or more concisely

```
/(.)(.{7})(.)(.)?/
```

Comment: or `/(.{1})(.{7})(.{1})(.?)/`

Answer (score 1):

You could almost certainly have solved this for yourself by reading either the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) or [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) manual pages.

As others have pointed out, the `?` marks a regex atom as being optional. You can also simplify your regex by omitting all of the `{1}` sequences.

```
/(.)(.{7})(.)(.)?/
```